# Confusion about implicit differentiation $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation

Today I learnt about implicit differentiation using this:

$\frac{d}{dx}(f)$ = $\frac{df}{dy} \times \frac{dy}{dx}$

I don't understand when doing implicit differentiation how the d/dy part works for y terms:

$\frac{d(y^2)}{dx} = \frac{d(y^2)}{dy}\times\frac{dy}{dx}=2y\frac{dy}{dx}$

Why is the derivative of $y^2$ with respect to $y$, $2y$? Do you assume it's a function of something else?
And similarly if you apply this same formula to an $x$ term (even though its not needed) you get:

$\frac{d(x^2)}{dx} =\frac{d(x^2)}{dy}\times\frac{dy}{dx}$

How does that simplify to the $2x$ I know it is?

Thanks

Comment: What is $y$ in your last differentiation? Take $y=x$ then it works perfectly.

Comment: @A.Γ. Its just an example, I'm not really sure, I thought of it as $y=x^2$ and $y=f$and did it using the formula at the top.

Comment: If $y=x^2$ it still works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, here they assume that $y$ is a function of something else.

Whenever we apply implicit differentiation like with $\frac{dy^2(x)}{dx}$, we sort of first forget it is a function of something else, say $x$, we just derive it using the chain rule and then we need to correct for this via the familiar additional factor:

$$ \frac{d y^2(x)}{d x} =2 y(x) \cdot\frac{d y(x) }{dx}$$

Actually implict differentiation often boils down to just using the chain rule. Notice that if $y$ is not a function of $x$, we get that $\frac{ d y}{dx} =0$ and the equation just reads $0=0$.

For your second case where you state:
$$\frac{d(x^2)}{dx} =\frac{d(x^2)}{dy}\times\frac{dy}{dx}$$ 
We could call $y=x^2$ because you really need to tell the reader what this new variable $y$ is in relation to the old variable $x$, else the derivative could be anything. We then get:
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{dy}{dy}\times\frac{d x^2 }{dx}= 1 \cdot 2x $$

In general we use implicit differentiation when there is some complicated variable dependence and you cannot directly express some variable **explicitly** in terms of the other. An example of such an equation would be:
$$t+ t^2 + 3z^2 + z^3 = 6$$
Using implicit differentiation we could construct the tangent line for $(t,z)=(1,1)$, we will derive both sides with respect to $t$, we do not know if $z$ is is a function of $t$ so we need to use the chain rule.

We would get: 
$$1+ 2t + 6z \frac{dz}{dt} + 3 z^2 \frac{dz}{dt} = 0$$
Now we plug in the value at (1,1) to get:
$$1+ 2 + 6 \frac{dz}{dt} + 3 \frac{dz}{dt} = 0$$
Or after rearranging:
$$9 \frac{dz}{dt}  = -3 \rightarrow \frac{dz}{dt}= -\frac{1}{3}$$
We get the tangent line $z= -\frac{1}{3}(t-1) +1$

Comment: Thanks a lot this really helped.

Comment: any time ;) we're all here to help

Comment: Hello, I just saw your edit. why dont the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ terms cancel out for the y terms as the $ \frac{dx}{dy}$ terms for the x terms. Or do we just not do that otherwise we can't rearrange for what we want ($\frac{dy/dx}$)

Comment: Maybe I should use different letters to make clear that $y$ is not always equal to $x^2$

Comment: ah so we assume x is a function of y but not the other way around?

Comment: It automatically IS, because the function is a relation between $x$ and $y$, but we only derive with respect to $x$. If you would use the chain rule like this for $X=x$:
$$ \frac{d}{dx} (X(x)^2)= 2X \cdot \frac{dx}{dx}=2X=2x$$
 I think you get what you mean by using the chain rule for a variable you don't need to use it for. Here I mean that $X$ is a function of $x$ (clearly).

Comment: But for that more complicated example you have done, for the $t^2$ term you get $\frac{d(t^2)}{dz}\times\frac{dy}{dx}$. And $z$ doesn't equal $t^2$ so how do we cancel that down to $2t$? Sorry if this isn't making any sense and I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are saying, where does $y$ come in? why are you introducing 4 variables?

Comment: Oh sorry I meant to do $\frac{dz}{dt}$ in place of $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: Okay, but that is the relation between $z$ and $t$? Else I do not know how to interpret this other than in terms of this so-called chain rule.

Comment: Maybe this is also interesting: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379569/can-someone-give-me-a-deeper-understanding-of-implicit-differentiation?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

You implicitly utilize the formula of [derivative of a composite functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) or a chain rule:
$$
f = y(x)^2, \qquad\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{d(y^2)}{dx},\\
f=g(y(x)),\qquad g(y)=y^2,\\
\frac{d}{dx}g(y(x))=\frac{dg(y(x))}{dy}\frac{dy(x)}{dx}=(2y(x))\frac{dy}{dx}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of $y^2$ with respect to $y$ is $2y$ because of the definition of derivative:
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(y+h)^2-y^2}{h} = 2y.$$

In the last expression you write 
$$\frac{d(x^2)}{dx} = \frac{d(x^2)}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}$$
but this is meaningful only when $x$ is a function of $y$. So assume $x = f(y)$. Then, by the first equation you mention in the question, the right hand side is
$$\frac{d(f^2)}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} = 2f(y)f'(y)\frac{dy}{dx} = 2xf'(y)\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x\frac{dx}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x\frac{dx}{dx} = 2x.$$